# Pacemaker and DRBD on Hyper-V

Tags: cluster-computing, hyper-v, pacemaker, drbd, stonith

I need to setup two-node Web cluster for Apache web site. I have Hyper-V infrastructure and only two nodes.
The points are load-balancing and high availability.

I installed and configured two VMs with CentOS 7, Pacemaker cluster, MariaDB 10. I configured Master/Slave ocf::percona:mysql resource in Pacemaker.

Next i need a shared storage for web site content. 
I created DRBD disk in dual-primary mode and GFS2 in top of it. I tested it without adding to Pacemaker. All worked fine but, to make it automaticaly promoted, i need to manage these via Pacemaker.

**The problem is that Pacemaker need fencing to create DRBD resource but there is no stonith agents for Hyper-V.**

I read that in previous version for CentOS 6 it was possible to create SSH stonith agent. I tried to do this, but pcs not works with it.

Is it possible to use Pacemaker in top of Hyper-V for now? Or may be exist another way to use DRBD in dual primary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many solutions but no one did not work well. 
I have made two-way file replication using [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd/wiki) instead.